# Installing Ubuntu After Download

Tags: installation, downloads

I downloaded the latest version of Ubuntu Desktop (13.04) the other day and think I might have missed something, as I didn't see any "Install"-related buttons or links following the download. The files are stored neatly under 'Tools-Downloads' (as my system is running on an older version of Ubuntu), but I still don't know how to install the new software at this point.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and given the fact that I'm a novice when it comes to the technical side of the Web, I would also appreciate that your recommendations be outlined in a step by step fashion.

PS: On a related note, can it also please be confirmed that the Ubuntu Desktop download is, in fact, for laptops as well as desktops (or is there a different version/package altogether for laptops [i.e. the system I'm inquiring about]).

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: How did you downloaded the latest version. Could you please comment on that. Because, if Ubuntu runs on an older version it will alert you to upgrade to a newer version when you're connected to the Internet. Further, there is only one distribution for both desktops & laptops.

Comment: What you've downloaded is an ISO image.  Once downloaded you need to create a bootable DVD, or USB.

Comment: Thanks guys. I did, in fact, upgrade through the 'Upgrade Manager', however, as I was running on an extremely old version of Ubuntu Desktop, I originally thought it would be best to download the newest version and simply re-install Ubuntu this way. I had to update (to the following version) a couple of times, but all is well now, and the issue has been resolved. I must say that this is an incredibly helpful community. I was afraid that I would be shunned for my lack of technical know-how, but instead several within the network responded in a more than professional way. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the ISO you downloaded can be used on both laptops and desktops

Since you downloaded an ISO file, to install, it has to be burnt onto a CD/DVD drive, or used to create a bootable USB. I would suggest reading how to burn your ISO file to a CD/DVD https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto

and how to use that CD/DVD as a LiveCD for installing it to your hard drive https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromCD

Or, you could upgrade Ubuntu with the Update Manager 
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/upgrade

Comment: Thanks very much. The issue has been resolved. I decided to upgrade through the 'Update Manager' (even if I had to go through the process a few times). I'm now running on 12.04 and it's great. Thank you once again.